# "do stretching" vs. "do stretches" which sound better? Are both of these grammatically correct?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, grammar

It seems like "do stretching" is more commonly used than "do stretches." Is that right? Which one sound better? I want to know which one is used normally.
Plus, are both of these grammatically correct? Or, perhaps do these have some differnces in meaning?

What I want to express is that when I go to the gym, I do some stretches(or stretching[uncountable noun]) for warm-up.

What I have written down is "I start with 5 minutes of walking for warm up, and do some stretching from head to toe then, I begin my strength training."

If there are more parts that sound awkward in the sentence, i would be very grateful to know.

Comment: I don't indulge in [calisthenic warm ups](http://www.mpcalisthenics.com/stretching/the-7-stretches-of-highly-flexible-people-2) myself, but my impression is most of those that do would use the straightforward plural noun *[some] **stretches***, rather than the gerund *[some] **stretching***. Having said that, both are syntactically fine, and *could* reasonably be used by native speakers. For the final example I'd probably say *...and do some **head-to-toe stretches***, but as implied above, it's not the kind of thing I'd be likely to want to express anyway.

Comment: Note that your example sentence doesn't actually say "do stretching".  It says "do *five minutes* **of** stretching".  That's a different structure!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you very much for your comment. So, I will go with ... do some head-to-toe stretches. What I really wanted to know was that which of these would more likely to be used by native speakers, as you said. I guess my question is pretty much be solved. Thank you!

Comment: And, @stangdon I thought that because I used 'and," this conjuction would connect those verbs "start" and "do," then "begin." If that's not right, I will go with .... do some head-to-toe stretches for 15 minutes, then I begin .... Would the sentence be okay, then? Thank you very much for letting me know, though! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Do* with a gerund (like *stretching*), though grammatical, is not very idiomatic. However, with a quantifier it is completely idiomatic.

So *do stretching* sounds odd ;but *do some stretching* (or *a bit of stretching* or *a lot of stretching*) is fine.

Now I think of it, the same is true for the nominal *stretches*: *do some stretches* (or *do a few stretches*) is much more natural than *do stretches*.

I think the difference between *do some stretches* and *do some stretching* is that the latter sounds less organised, and possibly less intentional. But the difference in meaning is not great.

Comment: I'd never have thought of that until you pointed it out, but you're quite right that including a "quantifier" often converts a "quirky" (but grammatical) form into something completely natural. Maybe *particularly* with gerunds, but I have to say I suspect your main reason for extending the principle to ***stretches*** is just that that particular usage isn't so familiar in the first place. *What exercises do you do? Not many - I mostly just do press-ups.* In that context, you'd only include ***a few*** if that was really true/relevant (as opposed to doing *a whole hour* of one exercise, say).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It helped me a lot. I will remember that 'Do' with a gerund is not very idiomatic, but with a quantifier! Also, 'do some stretching' sounds less organised. Thank you!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, honestly, I don't really understand what you suspect. Do you mean, this 'Do' + quantifier + activities does not always sound better, but just with some typical activities(ex. stretches but not press ups). Is that what you are talking about? Am I following you so far?

Comment: @R.Choi: What I suspect is that when Colin says *the same is true for the nominal **stretches*** (i.e. - that "unqualified" *I do stretches every morning* can be made more "natural" by including a modifier such as ***some***), he may be influenced by the fact that ***a stretch = a calisthenic exercise*** is far from being the first sense most of us would associate with the noun. But that's a very fine distinction. I think the primary point here is that when asked *What are you doing later?* the response *Dunno - maybe I'll do cooking / reading / sunbathing* sounds "odd" without ***some***.

Comment: I think I sort of understand now. Thank you very much for your kind explanation!

Answer (score 0):

How to express oneself regarding stretches:

I **do my stretching** before I exercise. I usually **do two quad stretches** per leg and two **bicep stretches** per arm and a **back stretch** using a yoga position on the floor or up against the wall.

I find that **doing stretches** helps me avoid muscle injury issues. Plus, **stretching** is just plain good for you. When do  you do  **your stretching**? Only before exercising or afterwards as well? What stretches do you do?

Any "exotic" ones like getting on a table and stretching the psoas muscle? Like dancers often do?

do [one's] stretching versus do stretches. One is the activity and a verb: do stretching and the other is just the noun.

When do you do your stretching? [engage in the activity of stretching]
Which stretches do you do? [the particular exercise]

Comment: Thank you very much for your example sentences. I can clearly see how those gerund and noun are different. I guess I should go with "... do some static head-to-toe stretches for 15 minutes, then..." Thank you!
By the way, what do you mean by "plain good?" What does that mean?

Comment: @R.Choi Thank you for your comment. ***just plain [adjective]*** is idiomatic: This tea is just plain good=The tea cannot be described any other way than being good. That movie was just plain bad.

Comment: I think you are good at writing example sentences! Thank you for your kind answer! :)